# How to split the list into sublists with length between 2 and 4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I want to write a function, which splits the list into sublists with length between 2 and 4, no more or less.

For example this list `["a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]` can turn into this `[["a","a","a","a"],["a","a","a"],["a","a"]]` or `[["a","a","a"],["a","a","a","a"],["a","a"]]`.

I wrote this function:

```
def split_list(lst):
    result = []
    sublist = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        sublist.append(lst[i])
        if len(sublist) == 4 or (len(sublist) == 2 and i == len(lst)-1):
            result.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
        elif len(sublist) == 3 and i == len(lst)-1:
            result.append(sublist)
    return result
```

but the output for `["a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]` is `[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]`, which is wrong.

For, list with less than three values, it must output that list: for example `["a","a"]` must not change

How could I do that?

Comment: Can you give an example - what's the desired *output*?  Maybe a few samples for diff. inputs.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. Here's one algorithm to solve:

1. If the sublist is of length 4, add it to the result and reset the sublist to [].
2. If the sublist is of length 3 and there are only 2 items left, add the sublist so that we don't leave ourselves with only one item in the last sublist
3. At the end of the loop, add the final sublist to the result (if it isn't empty)

This way we'll start our result with as many items of length 4 as possible, without allowing any of the items sets to have fewer than 2 items.

```py
def split_list(lst):
    result = []
    sublist = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        sublist.append(lst[i])
        if len(sublist) == 4:
            result.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
        elif len(sublist) == 3 and i == len(lst)-3:
            # there are only two items after this element, so add the
            # sublist to the result now
            result.append(sublist)
            sublist = []
    if sublist:
        result.append(sublist)
    return result
```

Let's test it out with lists from length 0 to 14.

```py
for i in range(15):
    print(split_list('a'*i))
```

gives a result of

```
[]
[['a']]
[['a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the input list on higher bound at once and then check if the last item/sublist fits the lower bound (to cover the main requirement):

```
def split_nsize(lst, low=2, high=4):
    if len(lst) <= high:  # base case
        return lst

    res = [lst[i: i + high] for i in range(0, len(lst), high)]
    before_last, last = res[-2], res[-1]
    if len(last) < low:  # ensure the last sublist fits the bounds
        res[-1] = [before_last[-1]] + last  # borrow value from before-last item
        res[-2] = before_last[: high - 1]  # cut before-last item
    return res
```

---

Testing:

```
lst = ["a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"]
print(split_nsize(lst))

[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
```

---

```
lst = ["a","a","a","a","a","a"]
print(split_nsize(lst))

[['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
```

---

```
lst = ["a","a","a","a","a"]
print(split_nsize(lst))

[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a']]
```

---

```
lst = ["a","a","a"]
print(split_nsize(lst))

['a', 'a', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking for a list with length less than 4, you can build a list of lists by slicing in traditional manner. Then, you're only concerned with the last sub-list. If it has a length of 1 you just adjust the last two entries appropriately. Like this:

```
def split_list(_list):
    if len(_list) < 4:
        return [_list]
    result = [_list[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(_list), 4)]
    if len(result[-1]) == 1:
        result[-1] = [result[-2][-1]] + result[-1]
        result[-2] = result[-2][:-1]
    return result
```